# Trying to pass url in vue and add API string after

Tags: vue.js

I'm looking to enter an image url in a text field, then have that url be displayed in an image tag but also have that original url modified by adding an API string at the end.

Here is the js:

```js
Vue.component('imagesinstagram', {
      props: ['url'],
      template: `
      <div class="container imgix-cell">
      <img class="img-variant" :src="url + '?q=60'"/>
      <div class="subtext">
         <br>Instagram
        </div>
      </div>
`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app_images',
  data: function() {
    return {
      myUrl: '',
      comparisons: [
        { id: 1, url: 'myUrl' }
      ]
  }
  }
})
```

Now here is the html:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter imgix URL" v-model="myUrl"/>
  <div>Entered URL: {{ myUrl }} </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <imagesinstagram
  v-for="comparison in comparisons"
  v-bind:url="comparison.url"
          ></imagesinstagram>
</div>
```

So essentially I enter an image url as a text field, it is returned as myUrl.  Then I am trying to use my vue component to call that same url but add ?q=60 afterwards as a query string.

It is just returning this in my codepen: https://cdpn.io/boomboom/v2/myUrl?q=60 . the myUrl should be the actual image url I entered.

Comment: What's the link between `myUrl` which is bound to your `<input>` field and `comparisons[0].url` which is bound to your component?

Comment: I thought by doing the v-for="comparison in comparisons" would refer to the id and myUrl sections.  Allowing me to v-bind that url.  It seems like it is having some effect since the image url resulted in v2/myUrl?q=60 .  It's just I wanted the myUrl to actually be the url I entered in the input section.

Comment: Here is it in a codepen Phil: https://codepen.io/daletom/pen/ExxvoqP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there are a few problems and I don't understand what you are trying to do with 'comparisons'. For starters, in your components you only have access to the component's props. So you have 'url' and not 'myUrl' ( which is only available in the parent component).

Then, in your data, you can't reference other parts of your data. When you say `{ id: 1, url: 'myUrl' }`, url will just be the literal string `'myUrl'`. This is not what you want.

I've made the changes and I think [this is doing what you mean](https://codepen.io/bbsimonbb/pen/qBBXoRM), but I don't have imgix.

Comment: Its saying ReferenceError: myUrl is not defined.  Here it is in a codepen: https://codepen.io/daletom/pen/ExxvoqP

Comment: That's exactly it Simon!!!  If you want to see what I was thinking of doing, you can go back to my codepen and enter this url https://assets.imgix.net/blog/woman-hat.jpg . It sizes it differently for all these different options. Thanks again